# Unable to submit Google Form field, with input filled out

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-chrome, tampermonkey

I am trying to create a scheduler that auto completes a google form for me. The Google form in question is: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfKdW2XyNNvbMkdQUGkZf8A6Bu_5SI_A5GuXbJPC2p23WidiA/viewform

I modfied this code from **https://github.com/jdowning100/Form-Autocomplete**

My code is here, I am using TamperMonkey:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         SchoolAttendanceFiller
// @namespace    http://www.github.com/jdowning100/Form-Autocomplete
// @version      0.2
// @description  Prototype form autocompletion
// @author       staticcg
// @match        http://*/*
// @include      https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfKdW2XyNNvbMkdQUGkZf8A6Bu_5SI_A5GuXbJPC2p23WidiA/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {

    'use strict';

    window.onerror = function ignore(){return true;};

    var SchoolInfo = {
        FirstName : "Imaginary",
        LastName : "Person",
        SchoolID : "ID "
    };
    //updated to fix hasValue patch.
    var valueControllers = document.getElementsByClassName("quantumWizTextinputPaperinputEl");
    // ^ fixes required question glitch
    var fields = document.getElementsByClassName("quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInput exportInput");
    var titles = document.getElementsByClassName("freebirdFormviewerComponentsQuestionBaseTitle exportItemTitle freebirdCustomFont");
    for(var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++){
        if(titles[i].innerText.valueOf() == "STUDENT FIRST NAME *".valueOf() || titles[i].innerText.valueOf() == "STUDENT FIRST NAME *".valueOf()){
            fields[i].value = SchoolInfo.FirstName;
            fields[i].setAttribute("data-initial-value", SchoolInfo.FirstName);
            fields[i].setAttribute("badinput", false);
        }
        if(titles[i].innerText.valueOf() == "STUDENT LAST NAME *".valueOf() || titles[i].innerText.valueOf() == "STUDENT LAST NAME *".valueOf()){
            fields[i].value = SchoolInfo.LastName;
            fields[i].setAttribute("data-initial-value", SchoolInfo.LastName);
            fields[i].setAttribute("badinput", false);
        }
        if(titles[i].innerText.valueOf() == "STUDENT LOCAL ID NUMBER [MOST BEGIN WITH LETTER L and is listed on your id card below your name] *".valueOf() || titles[i].innerText.valueOf() == "STUDENT LOCAL ID NUMBER [MOST BEGIN WITH LETTER L and is listed on your id card below your name] *".valueOf()){
            fields[i].value = SchoolInfo.SchoolID;
            fields[i].setAttribute("data-initial-value", SchoolInfo.SchoolID);
            fields[i].setAttribute("badinput", false);
        }
        for(var j = 0; j < valueControllers.length; j++){
            var fix = document.createAttribute("class");
            fix.value = "quantumWizTextinputPaperinputEl freebirdFormviewerComponentsQuestionTextShort freebirdFormviewerComponentsQuestionTextTextInput freebirdThemedInput modeLight hasValue";
            valueControllers[j].setAttributeNode(fix);
        }
    }

    try{
       document.getElementsByClassName("appsMaterialWizButtonPaperbuttonLabel")[1].click();
    }catch(error){
        console.log(error);
        document.forms[0].submit();
    }


    document.getElementsByClassName("quantumWizButtonPaperbuttonFocusOverlay exportOverlay")[2].click();

    document.forms[0].submit();
})();
```

The issue is Google Forms says that my response entry is a Required Question, like it is empty. I also am unable to edit the textbox with the script enabled.

HTML Code for the Form I've been using to debug:

```html
<div jscontroller="sWGJ4b" jsaction="EEvAHc:yfX9oc;" class="freebirdFormviewerComponentsQuestionBaseRoot hasError">
   <div class="freebirdFormviewerComponentsQuestionBaseHeader">
      <div class="freebirdFormviewerComponentsQuestionBaseTitleDescContainer">
         <div id="i1" class="freebirdFormviewerComponentsQuestionBaseTitle exportItemTitle freebirdCustomFont" role="heading" aria-level="3" aria-describedby="i4">STUDENT FIRST NAME<span class="freebirdFormviewerComponentsQuestionBaseRequiredAsterisk" id="i4" aria-label="Required question"> *</span></div>
         <div class="freebirdFormviewerComponentsQuestionBaseDescription" id="i2"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div jscontroller="oCiKKc" jsaction="rcuQ6b:vZc4S;O22p3e:zjh6rb;b2trFe:eVidQc;sPvj8e:d3sQLd;AHmuwe:h06R8;" class="freebirdFormviewerComponentsQuestionTextRoot">
      <div class="quantumWizTextinputPaperinputEl freebirdFormviewerComponentsQuestionTextShort freebirdFormviewerComponentsQuestionTextTextInput freebirdThemedInput modeLight hasValue" jscontroller="pxq3x" jsaction="clickonly:KjsqPd; focus:Jt1EX; blur:fpfTEe; input:Lg5SV" jsshadow="" jsname="YPqjbf" aria-disabled="true">
         <div class="quantumWizTextinputPaperinputMainContent exportContent">
            <div class="quantumWizTextinputPaperinputContentArea exportContentArea">
               <div class="quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInputArea">
                  <input type="text" class="quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInput exportInput" jsname="YPqjbf" autocomplete="off" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="i1" aria-describedby="i2 i3" disabled="" required="" dir="auto" data-initial-dir="auto" data-initial-value="Cory " badinput="false">
                  <div jsname="LwH6nd" class="quantumWizTextinputPaperinputPlaceholder exportLabel" aria-hidden="true">Your answer</div>
               </div>
               <div class="quantumWizTextinputPaperinputUnderline exportUnderline"></div>
               <div jsname="XmnwAc" class="quantumWizTextinputPaperinputFocusUnderline exportFocusUnderline" style="transform-origin: 133px center;"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="quantumWizTextinputPaperinputCounterErrorHolder">
            <div jsname="ty6ygf" class="quantumWizTextinputPaperinputHint exportHint"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div jsname="Rfh2Tc" class="freebirdFormviewerComponentsQuestionBaseValidationError" id="i3" role="alert">
      <div class="freebirdFormviewerComponentsQuestionBaseErrorIcon">
         <div class="freebirdMaterialIconIconEl freebirdMaterialIconIconUpdatedM2">
            <div aria-hidden="true" class="freebirdMaterialIconIconImage freebirdMaterialIconIconDarkIcon freebird-qp-icon-error-outline-b">&nbsp;</div>
            <div aria-hidden="true" class="freebirdMaterialIconIconImage freebirdMaterialIconIconLightIcon freebird-qp-icon-error-outline-w">&nbsp;</div>
            <div aria-hidden="true" class="freebirdMaterialIconIconImage freebirdMaterialIconIconM2Icon freebird-qp-icon-error-outline-red">&nbsp;</div>
         </div>
      </div>
      This is a required question
   </div>
</div>
```

What I did is added a attribute that google adds to finished textbox values called "hasValue" and that at first made it seem like it was going to work, as it fixed an issue where text was showing ontop of the placeholder text. But once submitted it still is acting like there is no value inside the textbox. What i am trying to accomplish is allow it to submit with autofilled text.

[This shows the response given](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCqWH.png)

Comment: had any solutions? looks like form input is an angular modal. tried manually dispatching ngModalChange event. no luck.